# Making button hidden on page load

Tags: javascript, css

Without using jQuery, I want my button with the text `"Process"` to not be visible (in all browsers) when the visitor comes to the page.  And when they select a value from the drop down other than the `first entry (blank)` one or `Have a Baby` for it to make the button visible.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Life Event Picker Calendar</title>
<script>
// Function being used to hide/unhide the button
function changeMessage(oElement) {
    if (oElement.value == "100") {
        document.getElementById("btn").style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else if (oElement.value == "0") {
        document.getElementById("btn").style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("btn").style.visiblity = "visible";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

...
...
<!-- Based on the selection here - the button below would be made visible --> 
<select id="leave" onchange="changeMessage(this);">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="5">Get Married</option>
  <option value="100">Have a Baby</option>
  <option value="90">Adopt a Child</option>
  <option value="15">Retire</option>
  <option value="15">Military Leave</option>
  <option value="15">Medical Leave</option>
</select>

 <!-- The button in question -->
 <button id="btn" onclick="getInfo()"type="button">Process</button>

...
... 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use CSS. `#btn{visibility:hidden}`. Normally I'd use display:none, but since you used visibility I went with your code.

Comment: or: `window.onload = function(){document.getElementById("btn").style.visibility = "hidden";
};`

Comment: Can you implement that into the jsfiddle so I can see it please??

Comment: I really don't understand why this question is downvoted..I guess if one person does it, people naturally follow along..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the `style="visibility:hidden;"` attribute to the button. Also, consider using `display:none` and `display:inline-block` instead of `visibility`.